# Templated constructors within template class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am trying to implement a Matrix class by defining rows and columns as template parameters. Also, I consider the Vector as a 'degraded' matrix class that share most of its code.

I would like to initialize my classes using initializers lists, as it was used in old c arrays way.

The problem comes when trying to give one and only one constructor to the class depending of being a Matrix or a Vector, so it is forbides in compiling time to assign a matritial initializer list to a vector and a vectorial initializer list to a matrix. I have tried with templates and with std::enable_if, but I am not able to fully understand the weird error messages of the compiler.

I post the reduced code stating the problem, clean of all of trials to solve it. In the comments I include further explanation of what I am trying to do. Anyone can knows how to do what I need?

```
#include <initializer_list>     

template<int R, int C, typename T=int>
struct Matrix
{
    T data[R][C];

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> initializers) { }//Do some stuff inside
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> initializers) { }//Do some stuff inside
};

template<int R, typename T=int>
using Vector = Matrix<R, 1, T>;

int main()
{
    Matrix<3, 3> m = { {1, 2, 3},
                       {4, 5, 6},
                       {7, 8, 9} };

    Vector<3> v = {10, 20, 30};

    Matrix<3, 3> m1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };//This must be avoided using templates in constructors or SFINAE 
    Vector<3> v1 = { {10, 20, 30} };//This must be avoided using templates in constructors or SFINAE

    return 0;   
}
```

Also, I post a coliru link with this same code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17b5e8c504c262d1

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Notice that `Vector<3> v1 = { {10, 20, 30} };` would be fine without the overload with inner `initializerl_list`, as "equivalent to"  `Vector<3> v1 = Vector({10, 20, 30});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++20, you might use `requires` to discards overloads:

```
template <int R, int C, typename T=int>
struct Matrix
{
    T data[R][C];

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> initializers) requires (C == 1)
    { /*..*/ }

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> initializers) requires (C != 1)
    { /*..*/ }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c89ac018c90b6679)

Prior of that, specialization:

```
template <int R, int C, typename T=int>
struct Matrix
{
    T data[R][C];

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> initializers)
    { /*..*/ }
};

template <int R, typename T>
struct Matrix<R, 1, T>
{
    T data[R][1];

    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> initializers)
    { /*..*/ }
};
```

or SFINAE can be used:

```
template <int R, int C, typename T=int>
struct Matrix
{
    T data[R][C];

    template <typename D = C, std::enable_if_t<D == 1, int> = 0>
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> initializers)
    { /*..*/ }

    template <typename D = C, std::enable_if_t<D != 1, int> = 0>
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> initializers)
    { /*..*/ }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was totally unaware of this interesting "requires" c++20 feature. Sadly, my current compiler does not support it, so I must take another way. Any further help with a more c++03/11 classic solution?

Comment: @Pablo: Other versions added.

Comment: Excuse me for keep asking, just wonder if the spetialization method can be simplified. I mean, that solution forces to unfold twice all the common code. It can be avoided using heredity, but I wonder if it is possible a partial spetializatoin of the constructor within the original class. I can open a new question if you prefer. Thanks.

Comment: Inheritance is indeed a way to avoid to duplicate common code, specialization of method should be full, not partial, and you cannot change signature (You might introduce some traits to have different signature, but then it is mostly specialization).